# Does the location falls here?

Tags: javascript, maps

I have a lattitude longitude JSON which forms a shape like {(45.76,56.67)(56.78,98.67)....}
and I have a another seperate latitude,longitude. I want to find out, Does the seperate locations falls inside the shape? Any help?

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) Do you have a specific programming question?

Comment: This is my usecase! It could be helpful if I find any solution in any programming language!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform for specific programming questions, see [tour]. Do you have a specific programming question?

Comment: `JSON which forms a shape like` - that's not valid JSON

Comment: what you're looking for is the [Point in Polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) problem - two possible methods to determine this are the Ray Casting Algorithm and the Winding Number Algorithm - I've written the latter successfully in javascript in about 20 lines of code

Comment: suggest you search for "javascript implementation of winding number algorithm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the polygon (shape) data is in the format

```
shape = [
    {x: 1, y: 2},
    {x: 3, y: 4},
    ...
]
```

and the point is an object like

```
target = {x: 5, y: 6}
```

Then the following code should determine if the point is within the polygon (shape)

```
const pointInPolygon = (point, polygon) => {
    const cross = (x, y) => 
        (y.x - x.x) * (point.y - x.y) - (point.x - x.x) * (y.y - x.y);
    let windingNumber = 0;

    polygon.forEach((a, i) => {
        const b = polygon[(i + 1) % polygon.length];
        if (a.y <= point.y) {
            if (b.y > point.y && cross(a, b) > 0) {
                windingNumber += 1;
            }
        } else if (b.y <= point.y && cross(a, b) < 0) {
            windingNumber -= 1;
        }
    });

pointInPolygon(target, shape);

    return windingNumber !== 0;
};
```

---

If, however the polygon is in the format

```
shape = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    ...
]
```

And the point is simply

```
target = [5, 6]
```

Then you'll either need to rewrite the function to use arrays or convert the data to the format expected - like this

```
const arrayToPoint = ([x, y]) => ({x, y});
const polygonArrayToPoints = polygon => polygon.map(arrayToPoint);

pointInPolygon(arrayToPoint(target), polygonArrayToPoints(shape));
```

However, I believe given lat/long order means that the `arrayToPoint` should actually be

```
const arrayToPoint = ([y, x]) => ({x, y});
```

---

Bonus:

If the data truly is

```
shape = [
    [lat, long],
    [lat, long],
    ...
]
target = [lat, long]
```

Then the `pointInPolygon` function is

```
const pointInPolygon = (point, polygon) => {
    const cross = (x, y) => 
        (y[1] - x[1]) * (point[0] - x[0]) - (point[1] - x[1]) * (y[0] - x[0]);
    let windingNumber = 0;

    polygon.forEach((a, i) => {
        const b = polygon[(i + 1) % polygon.length];
        if (a[0] <= point[0]) {
            if (b[0] > point[0] && cross(a, b) > 0) {
                windingNumber += 1;
            }
        } else if (b[0] <= point[0] && cross(a, b) < 0) {
            windingNumber -= 1;
        }
    });

    return windingNumber !== 0;
};
```